# Sort descriptor on string returns unwanted result

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I use this sort descriptor

```
NSArray *sortedObjects = [self.array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES], nil]];
```

The result is 10 and 11 are sorted alongside 1 and placed before 2.

```
index is 1/12
index is 10/12
index is 11/12  
index is 2/12  
index is 3/12
index is 4/12
index is 5/12
index is 8/12
index is 9/12
```

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Another option is to add a leading "0" to the months 1-9 before you insert them in your array.  And note that, if you may be doing a lot of sorting of dates like this you may want to map them yyyyMMdd.

Comment: If they really are dates, they should be stored as NSDate instances.  That'll take care of sorting, localization, and a whole slew of other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own comparison with

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayWithOptions:(NSSortOptions)opts usingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

or
another sort that allows a custom comparator.

Then split up the days and compare the month and then the day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of that class are the items that you are printing, presumably strings. This happens because the '/' character has an higher value than '0'.

You have to use a custom method or block to make the comparison. So initialise also the selector, not only the key:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sd= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey: @"index" ascending: YES selector: @selector(customCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedObjects = [self.array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[ sd ] ];
```

In your customCompare: method you should compare the objects.